# SQL, moving million records from a database to other database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a C# developer, I am not really good with SQL. I have a simple questions here. I need to move more than 50 millions records from a database to other database. I tried to use the import function in ms SQL, however it got stuck because the log was full (I got an error message The transaction log for database 'mydatabase' is full due to 'LOG_BACKUP'). The database recovery model was set to simple. My friend said that importing millions records using task->import data will cause the log to be massive and told me to use loop instead to transfer the data, does anyone know how and why? thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post the same question on more than one site at a time.

Comment: sorry i didnt know, i thought it is a different website, my bad

Comment: Your friend was wrong and you need a bigger disk in any case -- or you need to run this is a series of transactions to handle that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a database administration task. Ask it on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok this is confusing, first i was asked to ask at Programmers.stackexchange.com since this is not a specific question, and then my question was migrated back here, now someone else said this should be on dba.stackexchange.com.......

Comment: It is indeed a more or less typical DBA question :)

Comment: Yes, a database/ETL problem, and SQLserver certainly has tools to load data.  Check for a way to turn off transaction logging while you load this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are moving the entire database, use backup and restore, it will be the quickest and easiest.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx

If you are just moving a single table read about and use the BCP command line tools for this many records:

> The bcp utility bulk copies data between an instance of Microsoft SQL Server and a data file in a user-specified format. The bcp utility can be used to import large numbers of new rows into SQL Server tables or to export data out of tables into data files. Except when used with the queryout option, the utility requires no knowledge of Transact-SQL. To import data into a table, you must either use a format file created for that table or understand the structure of the table and the types of data that are valid for its columns.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and probably most reliable way is to bulk copy the data out via SQL Server's [bcp.exe utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx). If the schema on the destination database is *exactly* identical to that on the source database, including nullability of columns, export it in "native format":

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191232.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189941.aspx

If the schema differs between source and target, you will encounter...interesting (yes, interesting is a good word for it) problems.

If the schemas differ or you need to perform any transforms on the data, consider using text format. Or another format (BCP lets you create and use a format file to specify the format of the data for export/import).

You might consider exporting data in chunks: if you encounter problems it gives you an easier time of restarting without losing all the work done so far.

You might also consider zipping the exported data files up to minimize time on the wire.

Then FTP the files over to the destination server.

bcp them in. You can use the bcp utility on the destination server for the BULK IMPORT statement in SQL Server to do the work. Makes no real difference.

The nice thing about using BCP to load the data is that the load is what is described as a 'non-logged' transaction, though it's really more like a 'minimally logged' transaction.

If the tables on the destination server have IDENTITY columns, you'll need to use [SET IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) statement to disable the identity column on the the table(s) involved for the nonce (don't forget to reenable it). After your data is imported, you'll need to run [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) to get things back in synch.

And depending on what your doing, it can sometimes be helpful to put the database in [single-user mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345598.aspx) or dbo-only mode for the duration of the surgery: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx

Another approach I've used to great effect is to use Perl's DBI/DBD modules (which provide access to the bulk copy interface) and write a perl script to suck out the data from the source server, transform it and bulk load it directly into the destination server, without having to save it to disk and move it. Also means you can trap errors and design things for recovery and restart right at the point of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Use BCP to migrate data.

Another approach i have used in the past is to take a backup of the transaction log and shrink the log Prior to the migration. Split the migration script in parts and run the log backup- shrink - migrate iteration a few times.